# How To Parse CSV Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, csv

I want to parse CSV data, which is downloaded to the app. Right now I have the following data -  `"SPY",186.33,"3/17/2014","4:00pm",**+1.67**,185.59,186.77,185.51,93784328`. I used NSLog to display it on the console. What I want to do is read the **1.67** (or whatever it may be) and turn it into an `NSString`. The url where I get the information from will be consistent, but the numbers will change day to day. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to capture the row of data as a string (which it sounds like you've done, since you're able to `NSLog` it to the console), then you should be able to split the string apart like so:

```
NSArray *stringComponents = [yourDataRow componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *desiredComponent = [stringComponents objectAtIndex:4];
```

Then, your `+1.67` (or whatever) will be available as `desiredComponent`.

**Note:** This solution assumes that the `+1.67` component of the row will always occupy the 5th position in the row.

Comment: your solution will break if OP has a field like this `"hello, world"`

Comment: @meda Excellent point. However, OP's sample data looks like it came from a stock ticker which is highly unlikely to contain any commas as data.

Comment: Indeed, what i am trying to point out is to not parse data without parser. just like it is not a good idea to parse xml or json manually. you said it yourself **highly unlikely** but not never.

Answer (score 0):

I use CHCSVParser by Dave DeLong, it supports parsing this format from a file, NSString, or NSInputStream. Probably your best bet! https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser